# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in Symfony2

Tags: php, apache, session, caching, symfony

I'm getting a strange error in Symfony2.

In one very specific situation, my controller performs an action and renders a template, usual stuff, but after doing that, any request to the application returns an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error.

As there are no error messages at all, I tried to find where it fails using the debugger.

The list of steps that the application performs is the following:

web/app_dev.php

```
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

app/bootstrap.php.cache:2250

```
return $kernel->handle($request, $type, $catch);
```

app/bootstrap.php.cache:2948

```
$response = parent::handle($request, $type, $catch);
```

app/bootstrap.php.cache:2819

```
return $this->handleRaw($request, $type);
```

app/bootstrap.php.cache:2834

```
$this->dispatcher->dispatch(KernelEvents::REQUEST, $event);
```

app/cache/dev/classes.php:1764

```
return parent::dispatch($eventName, $event);
```

app/cache/dev/classes.php:1600

```
$this->doDispatch($this->getListeners($eventName), $eventName, $event);
```

app/cache/dev/classes.php:1667

```
call_user_func($listener, $event);
```

app/cache/dev/classes.php:2352

```
$listener->handle($event);
```

Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener.php:90

```
$token = $this->refreshUser($token);
```

Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener.php:165

```
return $token;
```

When it arrives to this line, the execution just stops. It is not an exception thrown by the application so, that may you think on a PHP or Apache error.
From that point the application is unusable, until you clear the cache of Symfony, and then the application works again. Although if I call again the same action, the error reappears. 
That seems to indicate that the framework has some responsibility over the error. Maybe related to the user authentication as the last lines executed are related to that.

I have no clue on how to go deeply in the problem.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Versions:
Symfony: 2.3.6
PHP: 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3
Apache: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

Comment: I had a similar problem for a while and it had to do with how my user entity implemented the __toString function. How is yours doing it?

Comment: There are PHP extensions used to cache PHP scripts in bytecode. Mostly APC, sometimes it is OPcache. You got the mentioned error in Chrome browser? In ffox you would get "The connection was reset". I use OPcache so I just reset it: opcache_reset(), and problem solved. Try to disable APC.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/-ChJqjeOIRg

Comment: The __toString function just returns the name attribute of the user, how can that affect?
I've been reading about the problems with APC, but disabling it doesn't solve the problem. Also this thread of Google Groups is quite old and the bug mentioned seems to be fixed in the version I'm using, 3.1.13.
In the other hand I realized that using PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 and APC 3.1.7 in another machine, the problem doesn't appear.

Comment: I completely removed the package php-apc and the error persists